# Relation between wavenumber and propagation constant

Tags: electromagnetism, waves, electromagnetic-radiation

What is the exact difference between wavenumber and propagation constant in an electromagnetic wave propagating in a medium such as a transmission line, cause i am a bit confused. Does it have to do with loss in the medium?

Comment: Did you check Wikipedia? http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber and http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant

Answer (score -1, accepted):

See ["Mathematical descriptions of opacity"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mathematical_descriptions_of_opacity), Wikipedia.

The [propagation constant](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant) has a real and an imaginary part. One of those is equal to the angular wavenumber, the other is proportional to the absorption coefficient.

Which is which (which is the real part and which is the imaginary part) depends on what definition you're using for the term "propagation constant". There is more than one definition in common use.

Answer (score 4):

**Here is the consensus for microwave engineering. Other fields of science may vary.**

$\newcommand{\j}{{\rm{j}}}$$\newcommand{\e}[1]{\,{\rm{e}}^{#1}}$
It was shown by [Hertz](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Heinrich_Hertz) that an arbitrary electromagnetic field in a source free homogeneous linear isotropic medium can be defined in terms of a single vector potential $\vec{\Pi}$.
Assuming $\e{\,\j\omega t}$ time dependency, a wave in the Hertz vector potential field can be written as:
$$\vec{\Pi}(x) = \vec{\Pi}(0) \e{-\gamma x}$$

The [propagation constant $\gamma$](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Propagation_constant#Definition) is a complex quantity:
$$\gamma = \alpha + \j\beta$$

where
$\alpha$ is the attenuation constant, and
$\beta$ is the phase constant.

However, since the attenuation in an air medium is negligible, it is customary to write the wave equation solely in function of a complex phase constant $\beta$:
$$\vec{\Pi}(x) = \vec{\Pi}(0) \e{-\j\beta x}$$

where $\beta = \beta' -\j \beta''$,
such that $\gamma \equiv \j \beta = \j (\beta' -\j \beta'') = \beta'' + \j \beta' \Rightarrow \beta'' \equiv \alpha$.

The free space [angular wave number](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wavenumber) $k_0$ is defined as:
$$k_0 \equiv \frac{\omega}{c_0} = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0}$$

The unit is $\frac{\text{rad}}{\text{m}}$

Only for [TEM waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode):
$$\beta = k_0 = \frac{2\pi}{\lambda_0}$$

Whereas for [TE and TM waves](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transverse_mode), separation of variables in a [Helmholtz equation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Helmholtz_equation) results in a [transcendental](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transcendental_equation) [dispersion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_%28optics%29) [function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dispersion_relation) that needs to be solved involving the free space wave number $k_0$ and a transverse wave number $\tau$.

In such cases,
$$\tau^2 = -\left(\gamma^2 + {k_0}^2\right) = \beta^2 - {k_0}^2$$

$$\Rightarrow \beta = \sqrt{{k_0}^2 + \tau^2}$$

Some worked out examples for EM surface waves can be found [here](https://hamwaves.com/stealth/en/index.html).

Answer (score -2):

The attenuation constant is specifically the imaginary part of the wave number (ki), while the wave number in dissipative media is the real part of the wave number (kr). Let me know what you think, because I just started studying this.

Comment: This answer is very unclear. What does "the wave number in dissipative media is the real part of the wave number" mean?